# How can I select a clicked item AND a subsequent item - Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

how can I select the item just clicked AND a subsequent item, using Jquery...
At the moment whenever I try to use the 'this' attribute along side another selector, it stops working...

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="refLink">9</a>
<span class="refPanelFloating">Blah blah blah</span>
```

Tried Jquery

```
$('a.refLink').click(function () {
    $(this,'span.refPanelFloating').wrapAll('<span class="refWrap" />');
});
```

Desired result

```
<span class="refWrap">    
    <a href="#" class="refLink">9</a>
    <span class="refPanelFloating">Blah blah blah</span>
</span>
```

At the moment I can only get it to work by selecting the initial 'a.refLink' tag... but on the final page there will be lots of them...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('a.refLink').click(function () {
    $(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<span class="refWrap" />');
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/M8weS/

The key is the [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) function which merges the result of the previous two chained calls into one list.

Comment: That works a treat. Thanks Alnitak...
out of interest though... What is the format for listing 'this' and another named item...
(this,'span.nameded)
or
('(this),span.named')
or...

Comment: I don't think there is a format - you can do "sela + selb" which is a selector that matches "sela" followed by "selb", but that doesn't work if all you've got for "sela" is 'this'.

Comment: Hmmm... Will keep trying. 
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: ask it as a new question, it's not clear enough here what you're asking for, since the answer will depend on the HTML structure.